# bazel: cannot find dependent header file for very simple case

Tags: c++, bazel

Firstly, my environment:

- Windows 10
- Bazel 2.0.0
- VS2017

I made a very simple C++ project using bazel. It has two `BUILD`s to test target referencing. The layout is:

```
- WORKSPACE
- libfoo
  |- BUILD
  |- foo.h
  |- foo.cpp
- bar
  |- BUILD
  |- bar.cpp
```

In `BUILD` file of libfoo, it defined a very simple library:

```
cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["foo.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["foo.h"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
```

And in bar's `BUILD` file, it declared an executable that deps libfoo:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "bar",
    srcs = ["bar.cpp"],
    deps = ["//libfoo:foo"],
)
```

, where `bar.cpp` called a function defined in libfoo:

```
#include "foo.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::clog << "bar main" << std::endl;
    say_foo(); // a function defined in libfoo
}
```

However when I compile bar using `bazel build "//bar:bar"`, the compiler claims `foo.h` cannot be opened (error code *C1083*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two ways of solving it:

Either you specify the `includes` property in `cc_library`

```
cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["foo.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["foo.h"],
    includes = ["./"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
```

Or you in `bar.cpp` you include `foo.h` as `#include "libfoo/foo.h"`.

Answer (score 2):

After more detailed view on official tutorial, I found that I misunderstood the function of deps, it does not add library's dir into *inc dir*.

Actually, `#include "libfoo/foo.h"` should be written in `bar.cpp` instead of `#include "foo.h"`, where the full relative path of target foo must be used.